# PHP Carbon incorrectly formatting UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, laravel, unix, php-carbon

I receive a UNIX timestamp from a URL like so:

```
/api/v1/order_variations/60?d=1508364000000
```

When I retrieve and try to convert the timestamp into a readable format, Carbon outputs the incorrect date.

```
$timestamp = (int)$request->input('d');
$date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($timestamp)->format('j F, Y');
dd($date);
```

The value of *$timestamp* is **1508364000000**.

Carbon converts this to **"25 February, 49768"** but it should be **"19 October, 2017"**

If I use:

```
Carbon::createFromTimeStampUTC($timestamp)->toDateTimeString();
```

I get the same result.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: This question was specific to the PHP carbon library and not converting Java timestamp to PHP. Please elaborate on your marking this thread a duplicate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unix timestamps is the number of *seconds* since the epoch (1 January 1970), but you're using the number of *milliseconds*. Just divide the value with 1000 to get the number of seconds.

```
$timestamp = (int)$request->input('d');
$timestamp = intval($timestamp / 1000); // convert milliseconds to seconds
```

This results in the value "18 October 2017 22:00:00". The only way to get the value "19 October 2017" from this would be to use a timezone with a +02:00 offset (CEST? SAST? Africa/Johannesburg?).